# retry chaining with onErrorReturnItem rxJava

Tags: rx-java2

I have create one observable

```
Observable<Map<Integer, String>> observable = Observable.create(s -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("getMultipleCitiesName ==="+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                List<String> cityIdsString = new ArrayList<>();

                for (Integer cityId : cityIds) {
                    cityIdsString.add(cityId.toString());
                }
                MultiValueMap<String, String> formParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
                formParams.put("cityIds[]", cityIdsString);

                // Call the Location Client to call the API
                Response<Map<Integer, String>> response = locationClient.getMultipleCitiesName(formParams);
                s.onNext(response.getData());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Inside Exception CITY NEW");
                s.onError(e);
            }

            s.onComplete();
        });
```

Now I want to add onErrorReturnItem() and retry() both.

So I tried it two ways

```
a) observable = observable.onErrorReturnItem(new HashMap<>()).retry(3);
b) observable = observable.retry(3).onErrorReturnItem(new HashMap<>());
```

**b)** is working (meaning retry and onErrorReturnItem) both are working
while in **a)** retry is not working?

Why is that

Answer (score 2):

Order of operators matters, this is how you have to interpret the chains:

(a) you're saying something like *Let take whatever comes from observable and if some error happens upstream then let have an observable that emit an empty `HashMap`(i.e calling `onErrorReturnItem`) and then `retry` on this observable(if some error is emitted)*. but no error is emitted by the observable `onErrorReturnItem` it just emit the empty `HashMap` followed by an `onComplete` signal. i.e whatever the error happens upstream is hidden by `onErrorReturnItem` and `retry` would never be signaled an `onError` to start retrying.

(b) you've saying completely the opposite, *Let take whatever comes from observable and if some error happens upstream let retry, if retry can't get any valid item after 3 attempts, then signal `onError` downstream and `onErrorReturnItem` will return an empty `HashMap`*.

Now it should be clear why (b) tend be what you're expecting to happens.